# Sum elements of a nested list and make a new list

Tags: python, list

I want to create a new list.

The new list will be 4 elements.

```
X = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Each of the 4 elements will be sums from 50 lists in a bigger list.

This bigger list has 50 elements all list. Inside each of the 50 nested lists.

Each of the nestedlists have these 5 elements

```
Nestedlist = [str, int, int, float, float] 

['Ohio', 11568495, 11568495, 262851.0, 44824.9]
```

In this part I've sorted through the data and changed elements 1-4 in the 50 nestedlists in to integers and floating numbers.

This is how I turned elements 1-4 into int and float:

```
for i, sd in enumerate(statesData):  
    sd = sd.strip().split(',')
    if i:  # omit element 0
        sd[1:] = int(sd[1]), int(sd[1]), float(sd[3]), float(sd[4])
    statesData[i] = sd
```

Now I want to find the sum of elements 1 2 3 4 of the nested lists and create a new list X (shown above):

So this is what I have:

```
sums = []
for e in statesData:
    if e:  
        e = sum(e[1]), sum(e[2]), sum(e[3]), sum(e[4])
        sums.append(e)
```

The output should look like this:

```
sums = [sum all nested lists element 1, sum of nested lists element 2, sum of nested lists element 3, sum of nested lists element 4]
```

the output I am getting is

```
unsupported operand type for +: int and str
```

How can I take a specific elements from multiple nested lists and make use of them?

If I want to use every element 2 of lists 1:50 inside list X

I feel this should be a lot easier. Even tho I am new I feel like this would be a common question. To take the same elements of multiple lists inside a larger list and play with the data.

Comment: What output are you actually getting? What's the question?

Comment: Output I am getting is:

'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What do you think `e` is? Try to print it (`print(e)` and even `print(type(e))`).

Comment: its an integer. But now the error is unsupported operand type for +: int and str. Dont understand because I am trying to skip element 0 which is the only string.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your for loop declaration,

```
for e in range(len(statesData)):
```

If `len(statesData)` is 4, then e will be 0,1,2,3 during the run of the loop. However, the code treats `e` as a list, indexing it multiple time here:

```
e[1:5] = sum(e[1]), sum(e[2]), sum(e[3]), sum(e[4])
```

Another issue is the sum, as it needs to take a list of values, not individual ints.

It would help if I could see what statesData looks like.  But, assuming that you want to get it in chunks of 4, you could do something like this...

```
for e in range(0, len(statesData), 4):
   newVal = sum(statesData[e], statesData[e+1], statesData[e+2], statesData[e+3])
   sums.append(e)
```

This for loop counts by 4, so e will be 0, 4, 8, etc.  Then, it uses e as an index to get 4 values of statesData. So the first loop it gets 0,1,2,3 and sums them.  Then it gets 4,5,6,7 and sums them, so on and so on.  It then appends that summation to the sums list.  I'm not sure this is exactly what you are looking for, so let me know where I went wrong.  But the specific error of int is not subscriptable is coming form the fact e is declared as an int in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip and map to apply operations in a columnwise direction:

```
allStates = list(map(sum,[*zip(*statesData)][1:]))
```